# Retrieve information from a mediawiki in a more structured way

Tags: rest, content-management-system, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

We would like to use a self-hosted mediawiki as a lightweight CMS to retrieve information from. However, the basic REST API is very limited in the way that it can retrieve content: this is probably because most information on wiki's is in unstructured form.

- Is it possible to add your own ID system to a mediawiki so that instead of getting a whole page or section worth of information, you could search for specific ID's (or even request content by ID in a REST-like way? for example `/:heading/:subheading/:sub-subheading` ?
- or if not, at least have a way of adding your own ID's so you could parse the information within a section in a more structured way?

Comment: I would recommend looking into Semantic MediaWiki

Comment: Hmm, I'm all for the Semantic Web but this wiki is really meant for private company use only :( The data could be converted to semantic data, but that is a project on it's own. I just need to be able to make mediawiki more structured... custom ID's / tags, extensions to the API etc. etc.

Comment: That's what Semantic MediaWiki is for -- making your data more structured. Just to clarify: Semantic MediaWiki has nothing (almost) at all to do with semantic html markup ot the “semantic web”. It's just an extension that lets you store structured data in your wiki, making it behave a bit like a collaborative graph database.

Comment: Ah yes, I meant converting the current mediawiki data to a graph-like database structure would take considerable time I suppose? If we would have chosen semantic mediawiki up front, that would not have been neccesary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using:
 - The default REST API, simplified using npm package nodemw.
 - Parsing wiki/text to HTML using npm package instaview.
 - Accessing / modifying the HTML serverside using npm package cheerio.

Long live free, unstructured BLOBs of text! go wikimedia go! omg.